# Reason ReWire Problem in ProTools LE 7.4.2

Tags: audio-recording, pro-tools, osx

Pro Tools LE 7.4.2 on my Mac running OSX Leopard will not detect Reason 3.0.4.

I have done the following:

- Installed reason first, then Protools
- Started a new session
- Created an aux input, instr. input, and MIDI input
- Then launched Reason

However, reason is not showing up under the plugin in drop down menu. It is not in either multi-channel or multi-mono.

I know that this is possible but why is it not working for me?

Comment: is there anyway you can get a more recent version of protools? One thing I've found is that ReWire has some problems with compatibility between older versions of software. I had to buy an upgrade to Melodyne when the older version my friend gave me wasn't compatible with any of the DAWs I switch between

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old but you will need to go and update your version of Reason to 3.0.5.  Per the proppellerhead website:

*This is a mac-only update designed to bring Intel Mac compatibility to Reason. This update also includes the latest version of ReWire, so non-Intel mac users still benefit a lot from this update. With the new ReWire, Reason's sample loading times are dramaticly reduced when working in a rewire session.*

More info: http://www.propellerheads.se/substance/words-wise/index.cfm?fuseaction=get_article&article=january-2007